# Perl Syntax Error - "syntax error line 15 near "} else" "

Tags: perl

I've got a **really** annoying problem in Perl. Here is my code:

```
if $password eq "a_secret";
{
    foreach $var (sort(keys(%ENV))) {
        $val = $ENV{$var};
        $val =~ s|\n|\\n|g;
        $val =~ s|"|\\"|g; 
        print '${var}=\"${val}\"\n'
    };
}
else
{
print "<html><head><title>Unauthorized</title></head><h1>Unauthorized</h1><body>You do not have permission to access \printenv\printenv.pl on this server.</body></html>";
}
```

When I execute this code I get the following error message:

```
syntax error line 10 near "else"
```

Any Ideas?
Note that some of the code has been removed.

Comment: What's with the -4??? This is a well worded, concise question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ($password eq "a_secret")
{
    foreach $var (sort(keys(%ENV))) {
        $val = $ENV{$var};
        $val =~ s|\n|\\n|g;
        $val =~ s|"|\\"|g; 
        print '${var}=\"${val}\"\n';
    }
}
else
{
print "<html><head><title>Unauthorized</title></head><h1>Unauthorized</h1><body>You do not have permission to access \printenv\printenv.pl on this server.</body></html>";
}
```

Comment: This answer offers no help to anyone except OP

Answer (score 7):

So many things to comment on. The error is in the very first line: you're missing parenthesis around the condition, and that `;` at the end is superfluous.

Next: Writing `\n` inside a single-quoted string `'...'` will not do what you want.

Then, not really wrong, but not exactly good style either: `print "..." } ;` should have the `;` and the `}` reversed.

Comment: Not to nitpick but the `;` at the end of the `if` conditional isn't superfluous, it's just wrong.  The one after the `foreach { }` is superfluous.  :)

Comment: I've tried and I still getting: `syntax error line 2 near "{"` and `syntax error line 9 near "}"`

Comment: @PythonKid: Are we supposed to mind-read now what you've changed it to?

Comment: I've changed all the errors pointed out but it's just not working.

Comment: So we ARE supposed to read your mind now. Sorry, cannot do that. So I cannot tell you what you did wrong this time.

Comment: Moritz did a great job of answering the question you did ask. If you have a new question, post it as a question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The first `if` test clause must be enclosed with `(` and `)`. Also, you cannot have `;` after the `if`-condition in line 1.

Comment: Dosn't work, when I remove the ';' I get: `syntax error line 2 near "{"` and `syntax error line 9 near "}"`

Comment: @Python Kid: 
It should be more like
`if ($password eq "a_secret")
{`

Comment: I've changed my code to the above, but I still get: `syntax error line 1 near ") {"` and `syntax error line 9 near "}"`